# post__in no longer works in wordpress 5.0.3

Tags: posts, widgets

I recently updated Wordpress to 5.0.3 and I got a problem on post__in, in particular I have this $query:

```
$query = array(
        'post_type'             => array('post'),
        'showposts'             => $instance['posts_num'],
        'cat'                   => $instance['posts_cat_id'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
        'orderby'               => $instance['posts_orderby'],
        'order'                 => 'dsc',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => $instance['posts_time'],
            ),
        ),
        'post__in' => array()
    );

if(!empty($instance["posts_specific"]))
{
    $query["post__in"] = explode(',', $instance["posts_specific"]);
}
```

for some reasons the widget doesn't display anymore the post specified in posts_specific, eg: 5435 (before all this mechanism worked).

I pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/HhZBQJwf) the full class. What is changed? I can't see anything reported in the official changelog.

Comment: What is the out put of `print_r( explode(',', $instance["posts_specific"] ) );`  or `print_r( $query["post__in"] );`?

Comment: @QaisarFeroz this return an array with the id of the post, something like: (5536, 285, 789)... if you check the full code at the bottom of the question (pastebin), this: `have_posts` return false, but before the update all worked well.. don't know what's happened

Comment: I copied your code into my local setup and it runs without fail. I am using latest WP 5.1.1. So, there no problem with your code. There might be some plugin or theme functionality ,causing the problem. Deactivate all plugins and then re-activate one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: @QaisarFeroz I disabled all the plugins and still same problem, I repeat: before worked, after wp update not work. I can't update yet to 5.1.1